# How to check if 2 directories have the same content

Tags: 20.04, directory, checksums

What's an easy way to check if 2 different directories have the exact same contents?

Comment: Make a tar file of both directories, and then take a hash? I'll post a full answer soon

Comment: How do you define contents? The contents of the file in it? Does that include the filenames of what is in the directory? What about the metadata (e.g., date modified) of said files?

Comment: Ok forgive my stupidity but I used a temp mail and forgot to save it so I lost that account. I need to figure out if 2 directories contain the same files, filenames folders and folder structure. No metadata like date modified though.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `find`, `sha1sum`, and a series of pipes can accomplish this goal:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 sha1sum | cut -c1-40 | sha1sum
```

This will give you an output like:

```
98f3a7c54a8f51dd86506a26d4d3bd90e6e4b821  -
```

<sup>**Note:** The trailing dash can be ignored, of course.</sup>

Run this on the path(s) that you would like to check, and you'll see whether two directories are the same or not. If they're not, you can begin editing the command to find the different files. One simple, albeit time consuming, ways to do this would be to remove the `| cut -c1-40 | sha1sum`, which will list each file and its corresponding sha1 hash.

#### How Does This Work?

|  | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `find /path/to/files` | returns list of items from the `/path/to/files` directory |
| `-type f` | include only files |
| `-print0` | print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character |
| `|` | and then |
| `sort -z` | sort the list, using null as the line delimiter rather than a newline |
| `|` | and then |
| `xargs -0 sha1sum` | run each value from the list through `sha1sum` |
| `|` | and then |
| `cut -c1-40` | take *just* the first 40 characters (the length of a sha1 |
| `|` | and then |
| `sha1sum` | generate a sha1 hash of the list of sha1s |

Comment: Your answer prints the full path to the directory in `xargs`,it will say that two directories are different even if the files are the exact same as the final hash will hash the full paths outputted from xargs... also why not just use `-exec` in find? This command works for two identical directories: `find ~/testdir1 -type f -exec sh -c "cat {} | sha1sum" \; | sha1sum`

Comment: You're right. I forgot the `cut -c1-40` bit, which would result in an inaccurate return. This is what I get for answering a question off the top of my head 